# Laravel - how get a single model instance not as collection, but single model from belongsToMany

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model, relation

I have this relation defined in one of my models. It is the simplest possible case.

```php
use \App\Models\Related;

public function entities()
{
    return $this
           ->belongsToMany(Entity::class, 'entity_related', 'related_id', 'entity_id');
}
```

Now, I want to create a relation which gets only one model from the table.

#### Current solution

I just defined the same relation, but with `->take(1)`. Crude, but it works. 
The downturn of this solution is that I need to do a `foreach` loop to get my desired single model.

```php
use \App\Models\Entity;

public function firstOfEntities()
{
    return $this
           ->belongsToMany(Entity::class, 'entity_related', 'related_id', 'entity_id')
           ->take(1); // <---
}
```

#### TO DO

How to properly define a relation which gets only one (just any) model instance, instead of creating a collection?

#### The desired usage

With the above completed I want to be able to use the single model in my template file inside a `foreach` loop:

```
@foreach($object as $o)
    <h2>{{ $o->singleEntity->name }}</h2>
    <p>{{ $o->singleEntity->description}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 5):

You could define an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) to get your first element:

```
/** MyModel.php */

use \App\Models\Entity;

// Your current relationship
public function entities()
{
    return $this
       ->belongsToMany(Entity::class, 'entity_related', 'related_id', 'entity_id');
}

// the accessor
public function getFirstEntityAttribute()
{
    return $this->entities()->first();
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
/** MyModelController.php */
$model = MyModel::find(1);
$entity = $model->first_entity;
```

---

Check [the docs related](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) to this topic.

Comment: We have a misunderstanding, I guess. 
I need the output model in my view file inside populated foreach loop, not in controller.

Comment: @Peter you can absolutely do this. Just return the `$model` or `$entity` to your view to be able to use it: `return view('my_view')->with('entity', $entity);`